# API & Service for City name, Country lookups

Tags: api, rest, city

Is there a public City lookup and API (RESTful) available somewhere?
As opposed to holding our own City list.

Comment: Consider asking these kind of questions at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This API looks comprehensive:
[Geobytes.com free ajax cities API](http://www.geobytes.com/free-ajax-cities-jsonp-api.htm)